# Cannot lose focus of textbox with binded datasource after writting and erasing

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, bindingsource, tableadapter

I have a `Winform` with textboxes binded to a `bindingsource` using a `tableadapter`.
When I write something in a textbox and delete it the form won't let me remove the focus from the textbox.

I do not understand how it is possible if I can leave the textbox empty, but if I write something then I can no longer leave it empty.

What could be causing this anormal behavior?

I dont know how to explain it in deep, so please be open to ask for more information.

Comment: You most likely are dealing with a field which has some kind of validation. Set the [AutoValidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autovalidate?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the form to `EnableAllowFocusChange`. The default value is `EnablePreventFocusChange` which is very annoying.

Comment: If you have just `e.Cancel = true;` in a `Validating` even handler (which prevents focus change), you could replace the validation error with `ErrorProvider.SetError()`, to give visual feedback of the problem and not set `e.Cancel = true;`. In case an empty Field is a validation failure, that is. Maybe your validation procedure needs some tweaking. What is validating the data input? Did you use Visual Studio's automatic generation of databindings? If so, you may need some *manual intervention*. Or do everything in code.